# SAS Pulling string variables from a csv file

Tags: sas

**SOLVED** (per Neil Neyman's comment):

`&var1` is not the same as `var1`.

```
DATA local.trow; 
    INFILE csvfile FIRSTOBS=&i OBS=&i;
    INPUT var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $;
    call symput('var1',var1); *Added line;
    call symput('var2',var2); *Added line;
    call symput('var3',var3); *Added line;
    call symput('var4',var4); *Added line;
RUN;
```

Adding the lines marked with "*Added line;" solved the issue.

---

**QUESTION**

Disclaimer: I am very new to SAS and have been struggling with issues in this code for a while.

In a loop, I am trying to import string variables from a CSV file, one of which I then pass to a remote server (`var1`), but I'm running into an issue.  If I include `%let var1 = 'XXE';` at the top of the code and exclude the portion where I'm pulling the variables from my csv file, remote execution works fine and I get the output I would expect.

However, if I run the code as is, it appears to not treat the string variables as expected.  For instance, the `PROC PRINT` statement produces the expected output (i.e. it shows the 4 variables), but the title does not show up properly--it appears that `var1` is skipped altogether, while `i`(with a value of 1) and `m` (with a value of 2007) are displayed.  The title shows up as "Title - 1 2007".  The log displays the following error near the title line:

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference VAR1 not resolved.
```

The remote submit does not work either, but instead produces the following error while highlighting `&VAR1`:

```
ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string,
              a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value.
```

I'm really confused by this error because the `PROC PRINT` statement is able to print the variables (which do in fact visually appear to be strings).  Is a "quoted string" a different type of variable?

If I explicitly declare `var1` at the top of the code or manually enter `'XXE'` into the `WHERE` clause, the remote query executes.

Could it be that am I handling the text file incorrectly?  It looks like this:

```
XXE XXA XXB XXC
XXM XXN XXI XXP
...
```

My code:

```
LIBNAME local 'C:\...\Pulled Data\New\';
FILENAME csvfile 'C:\...\Pulled Data\New\indexes.txt';

%macro getthedata(nrows,ystart,yend); *nrows is the number of rows in the text file;

    %GLOBAL var1 var2 var3 var4;

    %do i=1 %to &nrows;
        %do m=&ystart %to &yend;

            DATA local.trow; 
               INFILE csvfile FIRSTOBS=&i OBS=&i;
               INPUT var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $;
            RUN;

            PROC PRINT DATA = local.trow;
            TITLE "Title - &i. &var1. &m";
            var var1 var2 var3 var4;
            RUN;

            proc export data=local.trow
                outfile="C:\...\Pulled Data\New\Indices_&i._&m..csv"
                dbms=csv replace;
            run;

            signon username=_prompt_;
            %syslput VAR1 = &var1;
            rsubmit;
                    libname abc'server/sasdata';    
                    data all2009;
                         set abc.file_2007:; 
                         by index date time;
                         where index in (&VAR1) and time between '8:30:00't and '12:00:00't;
                    run;
            endrsubmit;

        %end;
    %end;
%mend getthedata;

Options MPRINT;

%getthedata(1,2007,2007)
```

Comment: Where do you enter values into those macro variables? I see you declare them as global, so they exist. But you never set a value for them.

Comment: I try to set them 4 lines down, here: `DATA local.trow; INFILE csvfile FIRSTOBS=&i OBS=&i;.....`

Comment: But &var1 is not the same as var1.  Try placing after that line `call symput('var1',var1); call symput('var2',var2); #etc;`

Comment: Neil, your comment allowed me to answer this question.  I will include it in the body of my question.  If you want to edit your answer to include it, I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

&var1 is not the same as var1. Add the call symput() lines described below to assign the datastep values to the macro variable values.

```
 DATA local.trow; 
     INFILE csvfile FIRSTOBS=&i OBS=&i;
     INPUT var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $;
     call symput('var1',var1); 
     call symput('var2',var2);
     call symput('var3',var4); 
     call symput('var4',var4);

 RUN;
```

**Other Notes**

Seems a strange way to go about this, but you said you are new to SAS so maybe I could give you some pointers?

1. Create the entire dataset at once outside the macro

   ```
   data local.trows;
     length var1 var2 var3 var4 $3;  *assuming vars really are only 3 chars;
     infile csvfile; *this is not really a csv file, it looks space-delimited.;
                      *confusing to name it as such;
     input var1 var2 var3 var4;
   run;
   ```
2. I'm not getting why there's a separate output csv file for each row? Is that really what you need?
3. Once you have your dataset your macro can do something like:

   ```
   %macro getthedata(mdataset)
     data _null_;
      set &mdataset; #add mdataset as a macro parameter;

       /* automatically assigning nrows based on dataset; */
       if last then call symput('nrows',_n_); 

     run;     

     %do i=1 to &nrows;
        data _null_;
         set &mdataset;
         if &i=_n_ then do;
            call symput('var1',var1);
            call symput('var2',var2);
             /*
               etc... Doesn't seem like these really should be
               globals since they change every iteration, and
               don't seem needed outside of the macro?
              */

        run;
        /** now you have your vars set for the current iteration 
            and proceed with your connect code **/
   ```
4. It seems you are just overwriting this dataset with every iteration. Is that what you want to do? Or is there some other code/macro variables you left out for this question?

   ```
   libname abc'server/sasdata';    
               data all2009;
                    set abc.file_2007:;
   /*seems to be a random colon here ^  by the way*/
   ```

Comment: Hi Neil, your comment under my question actually answered my question exactly.  In answer to a few of your questions above, I have in fact left off a significant portion of the code that was not directly relevant to the `VAR1` issue.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Mr.Kinn OK great, I added that comment to the answer